# What is & How to know the default screenshot's window size of browsers in Selenium?

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, pytest-django

I ran the code below to take 3 screenshots of Django Admin on Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox. *I use [Django](https://github.com/django/django), [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium):

```py
import os
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

def take_screenshot(driver, name):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join("screenshot", os.path.dirname(name)), exist_ok=True)
    driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join("screenshot", name))

@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome", "edge", "firefox"], scope="class")
def driver_init(request):
    if request.param == "chrome":
        web_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        request.cls.browser = "chrome"
    if request.param == "edge":
        web_driver = webdriver.Edge()
        request.cls.browser = "edge"
    if request.param == "firefox":
        web_driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        request.cls.browser = "firefox"
    request.cls.driver = web_driver
    yield
    web_driver.close()

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_init")
class Screenshot:
    def screenshot_admin(self, live_server):
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (live_server.url, "/admin/")))
        take_screenshot(self.driver, "admin/" + self.browser + ".png")
```

Then, I could take 3 screenshots which have different window size depending on the browsers as shown below:

`chrome.png`:

[image: chrome.png]

`edge.png`:

[image: edge.png]

`firefox.png`:

[image: firefox.png]

So, what is & how can I know the default screenshot's window size of the browsers in Selenium?

Comment: Have you tried `save_full_page_screenshot(filename)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_window_size()](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#get-window-size) to get the screenshot's window size of the browsers in Selenium as shown below:

```py
...

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_init")
class Screenshot:
    def screenshot_admin(self, live_server):
        print(self.driver.get_window_size()) # Here
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (live_server.url, "/admin/")))
        take_screenshot(self.driver, "admin/" + self.browser + ".png")
```

Output:

```
$ pytest -q -rP
...
..                              [100%]
=============== PASSES ================ 
_ Screenshot.screenshot_admin[chrome] _ 
...
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
{'width': 945, 'height': 1012}
__ Screenshot.screenshot_admin[edge] __ 
...
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
{'width': 945, 'height': 1012}
_ Screenshot.screenshot_admin[firefox] _
...
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
{'width': 1292, 'height': 934}
3 passed in 18.33s
```

In addition, you can get `width` and `height` separately as shown below:

```py
...

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_init")
class Screenshot:
    def screenshot_admin(self, live_server):
        print(self.driver.get_window_size().get('width')) # Here
        print(self.driver.get_window_size().get('height')) # Here
        print(self.driver.get_window_size()['width']) # Here
        print(self.driver.get_window_size()['height']) # Here
        self.driver.get(("%s%s" % (live_server.url, "/admin/")))
        take_screenshot(self.driver, "admin/" + self.browser + ".png")
```